# Ruby: how to make class return true?

Tags: ruby, class, methods, hash

I'm a ruby beginner, and I'm not sure how to make `test` return 'true'

```
class Hash
  def in(*)
  end
end

# cannot alter below this line
def test
  { a: 1 }.in(:a) == 1
end

puts "test: #{test}"
```

From my understanding, the `Hash` class has a method inserted, but I don't know how to get the 'value' of the passed argument, if that makes any sense.  Either way, I'm pretty lost.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: The way you would actually solve this is `{ a: 1 }.key?(:a)`. In general avoid reopening (monkeypatching) the classes in the Ruby core. This both avoids causing conflicts between your code and other peoples code and there are many pitsfalls since these classes are actually implemented in C and don't always behave like actual Ruby classes. There are better ways to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The in method in the Hash class was not defined to return anything.

You need to define the in method in the hash class:

```
class Hash
  def in(key)
    self[key]
  end
end

def test
  { a: 1 }.in(:a) == 1
end

puts "test: #{test}"
```